# Selected option only appear as [object HTMLSelectElement] in alert box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to place a selected option in an alert box in JavaScript after scanning a QR Code to test if my selected option will appear in the alert box. However, when I scan the QR code, the decoded QR code string will appear but not the selected option, which only appears as [object HTMLSelectElement]. Here is my code in HTML with PHP.

```
<div class="scan-qr-container">
                <button class="btn" onclick="scanQRCode()">Scan QR Code</button>
                <video class="preview" id="preview"></video>
                <select id='selected'>
                    <?php

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<option>";
        echo "Select Event";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value=\"\">" . $row['event_name'] . "";
        }
        echo "</option>";

    } else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
}
?>
</select>
</div>
```

And this is my code in JavaScript.

```
function scanQRCode() {
  let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
    video: document.getElementById("preview"),
    mirror: false,
  });

  scanner.addListener("scan", function (content) {
    var selectedEvent = document.getElementById("selected");
    alert(content);
    alert(selectedEvent);
  });}
```

My sample event names are "Test Event 1", "Test Event 2", and "Test Event 3". If I select "Test Event 1", it will only appear as [object HTMLSelectElement]. Help would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you actually did alert only a DOM-element. Alert `selectedEvent.value` and see what happens. For debugging purposes, I’d recommend to use `console.log` rather than alerts, it saves you a lot of alert confirmations.

Comment: You tried to show the whole element, not just it's value.

Comment: Hello @Psi! I have tried your suggestion to replace selectedEvent with selectedEvent.value, however it only leaves an empty value.

Comment: then it’s value is empty.  from your code you can see that you only produce options with empty values: `echo "<option value=\"\">"`. For me it’s not a surprise. What did you expect to see?

Comment: @Psi Thank you for that comment. I have changed this line "echo "<option value=\"\">" . $row['event_name'] . "";" into this "echo "<option>" . $row['event_name'] . "</option>";".